# React-Native + Flex not responding to orientation change

Tags: ios, flexbox, react-native

I am writing a Universal iPhone/iPad application using React-Native. However I am struggling to render my view correctly when the orientation changes. Following is the source code for js file:

```
'use strict';
    var React = require('react-native');

    var {
      Text,
      View
    } = React;

    var CardView = require('./CardView');

    var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
      container:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      }
    });

    class MySimpleApp extends React.Component {
      render() {
         return <View style={styles.container}/>;
      }
    }

    React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => MySimpleApp);
```

This is how it renders in Portrait (which is correct): 
[image: Portrait]

However when the device is rotated. The red view does not rotate accordingly.
[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 24):

The simplest way is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    }

    this.onLayout = this.onLayout.bind(this);

  }

  onLayout(e) {
    this.setState({
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View 
        onLayout={this.onLayout}
        style={{width: this.state.width}}
      >
        <Text>Layout width: {this.state.width}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend this to everyone

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize you need to pass the onLayout as a prop to the view...thought it was more along the lines of componentWillMount, etc., =)

Comment: Or you can take a look at react-native-styleman library, it gives you media queries which lets you handle this in styles only without you having to handle the event manually.

Answer (score 15):

It pretty simple to respond orientation change in react native. Every view in react native have a listener called **onLayout** which get invoked upon orientation change. We just need to implement this. It's better to store dimension in state variable and update on each orientation change so that re-rendering happens after change.  Other wise we need to reload the view  to respond the orientation change.

[image]

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";

 import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Dimensions } from "react-native";

 var { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default class Com extends Component {
constructor() {
    console.log("constructor");
    super();
    this.state = {
        layout: {
            height: height,
            width: width
        }
    };
}
_onLayout = event => {
    console.log(
        "------------------------------------------------" +
            JSON.stringify(event.nativeEvent.layout)
    );

    this.setState({
        layout: {
            height: event.nativeEvent.layout.height,
            width: event.nativeEvent.layout.width
        }
    });
};

render() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props));
    return (
        <View
            style={{ backgroundColor: "red", flex: 1 }}
            onLayout={this._onLayout}
        >
            <View
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: "green",
                    height: this.state.layout.height - 10,
                    width: this.state.layout.width - 10,
                    margin: 5
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work. The onLayout function was fired when the app was started, but rotating the simulator didn't re-fire that event.

Comment: I have tried to use _onLayout but it sends invalid layout.
it shows width as 1024 and height as 1024.

Comment: eventSize: {"width":1024,"x":0,"height":1024,"y":0}
width: 768, height: 1024

It shows wrong data for onLayout. Actually the view is in landscape still show data of portrait and event show wrong data

Answer (score 13):

For more recent versions of React Native, orientation change doesn't necessarily trigger onLayout, but `Dimensions` provides a more directly relevant event:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
            height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
        };
        Dimensions.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
            this.setState(e.window);
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (            
            <View
                style={{
                    width: this.state.width,
                    height: this.state.height,
                }}
            >
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Note that this code is for the root component of an app. If using it deeper within the app, you will need to include a corresponding removeEventListener call.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening for me. Will need to use Dimension for this.

Comment: For a new RN project created in March 2020 I also had to add `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use react-native-orientation to detect and perform changes on orientation change.

```
var Orientation = require('react-native-orientation');
```

Also use Dimension class which return size(width, height).

```
Dimensions.get('window')
```

Use these methods to play with orientations

```
componentDidMount() {
    Orientation.lockToPortrait(); //this will lock the view to Portrait
    //Orientation.lockToLandscape(); //this will lock the view to Landscape
    //Orientation.unlockAllOrientations(); //this will unlock the view to all Orientations
    // self = this;
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    Orientation.addOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('componentWillUnmount');
    Orientation.getOrientation((err,orientation)=> {
        console.log("Current Device Orientation: ", orientation);
    });
    Orientation.removeOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
  }

  _orientationDidChange(orientation) {

    console.log('Orientation changed to '+orientation);
    console.log(self);

     if (orientation == 'LANDSCAPE') {
       //do something with landscape layout
       screenWidth=Dimensions.get('window').width;
       console.log('screenWidth:'+screenWidth);
     } else {
       //do something with portrait layout
       screenWidth=Dimensions.get('window').width;
       console.log('screenWidth:'+screenWidth);

     }

     self.setState({
       screenWidth:screenWidth
     });

   }
```

I also used this but It's performance is too low.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Neither `onLayout` or `Dimensions.addEventListener` worked for us in React 16.3.

Here's a flexbox hack which made the image resize on change of orientation. (We also used React's nice but poorly documented ImageBackground component to get text on top of the image):

```
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.imageRowWithResizeHack}>
          <ImageBackground
            style={styles.imageContainer}
            imageStyle={styles.thumbnailImg}
            source={{ uri: thumbnailUrl }}
          >
            <View style={styles.imageText}>
              <Text style={styles.partnerName}>{partnerName}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{title.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            </View>
          </ImageBackground>
          <View style={styles.imageHeight} />
        </View>
      </View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'relative',
    flex: 1
  },
  imageRowWithResizeHack: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  imageHeight: {
    height: 200
  },
  thumbnailImg: {
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  },
  imageText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 30,
    left: TEXT_PADDING_LEFT
  },
  partnerName: {
    fontWeight: '800',
    fontSize: 20,
    color: PARTNER_NAME_COLOR
  },
  title: {
    color: COLOR_PRIMARY_TEXT,
    fontSize: 90,
    fontWeight: '700',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 20
  },
});
```

The `imageHeight` style will set the height of the View component (which is invisible to the user), and Flexbox will then automatically flex the image on the same row to be of the same height. So you're basically setting the height of the image in an indirect manner. Flex will ensure it flexes to fill the entire container on orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found an answer to this. Need to implement the following in our viewcontroller and call refresh our ReactNative view inside it.

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation

Comment: would you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using [Exponent](https://getexponent.com/) you just need to remove the [`orientation`](https://docs.getexponent.com/versions/v14.0.0/guides/configuration.html#orientation) key from your `exp.json`.

Comment: we have no `exp.json`

Answer (score 0):

Appart from the answer given by user `Rajan Twanabashu` you can also use the [react-native-styleman](https://github.com/anubhavgupta/react-native-styleman) library to handle orientation change very easily:

Here is an example of how you would do that:

```js
import { withStyles } from 'react-native-styleman';

const styles = () => ({       
    container: {
        // your common styles here for container node.
        flex: 1,
        // lets write a media query to change background color automatically based on the device's orientation 
        '@media': [
          {
             orientation: 'landscape', // for landscape
             styles: {                 // apply following styles
                // these styles would be applied when the device is in landscape 
                // mode.
                 backgroundColor: 'green'
                 //.... more landscape related styles here...
             }
          },
          {
             orientation: 'portrait', // for portrait
             styles: {                // apply folllowing styles
                // these styles would be applied when the device is in portrait 
                // mode.
                 backgroundColor: 'red'
                 //.... more protrait related styles here...
             }
          }
        ]
    }
});

let Component = ({ styles })=>(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Some Text</Text>
    </View>
);

// use `withStyles` Higher order Component.
Component = withStyles(styles)(Component);

export {
  Component
};
```